# What is the best service for a GCP FTP Node App?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

Ok, so a bit of background on what we are doing.
We have various weather station and soil monitoring stations across the country that gather up data and then using FTP, upload to a server for processing.
Note: this server is not located in the GCP, but we are migrating all our services over at the moment.

Annoyingly FTP is the only service that these particular stations allow.  Newer stations thankfully are using REST APIs instead, so that makes it much simpler.

I have written a small nodejs app that works with [ftp-srv](https://github.com/trs/ftp-srv).  This acts as the FTP server.
I have also written a new FileSystem class that will hook directly into Google Cloud Storage.  So instead of getting a local directory, it reads the GCS directory.

This allows for weather stations to upload their dump files direct to GCP for processing.

My question is, what is the best service to use?

First I thought using App Engine, since its just a small nodejs app, I don't really want to have to go and create a VM for it just to run this.
However, I have found that I have been unsuccessful to open up port 21 and any other ports used for passive FTP.

I then thought using Kubernetes Engine.  To be honest, I don't know anything at all about this, as of yet.  But it seems like its a bit of an overkill just to run the small app.

My last thought would be to use Compute Engine.  I have a working copy with PROFTPD installed and working, so I know I can get the ports open and have data flowing, but I feel that it's a bit overkill to run a full VM just for something that is acting as an intermediary between the weather stations and  GCS.

Any recommendations would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes just for FTP would be using a crane to lift your fork.

Google Compute Engine and PROFTPD will fit in a micro instance at a whopping cost of about $6.00 per month.

The other Google Compute services do not support FTP. This includes:

1. App Engine Standard
2. App Engine Flexible
3. Cloud Run
4. Cloud Functions

This leaves you with either Kubernetes or Compute Engine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good to know about the ones that don't support FTP, I had gathered that App Engine didn't support it after spending hours trying to get it to work on that.  I thought Kubernetes might be overkill, but also thought GCE would be too, but that looks to be my only option, so I will roll with that, thanks!